# Как вызывать EditText.setError() по нажатию на его иконку?

Tags: android

У меня есть `EditText` с `.setError`. Если нажимается кнопка, а `EditText` пустой, то выскакивает сообщение об ошибке. Проблема в том, что сообщение выскакивает, закрывая нижнее `EditText`'ы! Как сделать, чтобы сообщение всплывало, по нажатию на красный круг и, при повторном нажатии, убиралось?

Comment: Иконку ошибки показывать, как `drawableRight`, и ручками показывать, нгапример, `PopupWindow` по клику на эту иконку.

Comment: @metalurgus, с `PopupWindow` все понятно, но что такое `drawableRight`?

Comment: Как насчет погуглить? https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&es_th=1&ie=UTF-8#q=android+drawableright

Comment: @metalurgus, да в том-то и проблема, что гуглить я умею только на русском, а на английском боооольшие проблемы с пониманием. Ладно, я в переводчик.